# ES6 conditional if statement to check if arrays are empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I can't seem to get my jsx es6 react if statement to work.. What am I doing wrong?

```
const otherVariables = doesntMatter;    

return (
...
    <div>
    {if (props.student.length == null && props.teacher.length == null) => (
       <p>empty</p>
    ) : (
       <p>not empty</p>
    )} 
   </div>
...
)
```

How can i check if both arrays are empty?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do `if ( props.student.length <= 0 && props.teacher.length <= 0 ) {  } else {  }`

Comment: Even better, since array lengths are strictly non-negative: `if( props.student.length + props.teacher.length == 0)`

Comment: Sure, but i'm throwing this into return() so this would go inline with html in react.

Comment: Then use a ternary

Comment: @adeneo yes! how can i do that for checking length?

Answer (score 8):

There is a syntax error, you are testing an lambda expression.

You can do something like

```
return !!props.student.length && !!props.teacher.length ? <p>not empty</p> : <p>empty</p>;
```

Comment: I made an edit to my post. That will not work within return() as theres other things in there. It needs to be inline with the html... I'm not sure of the syntax :\

Comment: Why exactly use `!!` coercion instead of simply `props.student.length && props.teacher.length`?

Comment: Actually this returns `empty` for me either way.

Comment: @Aaron this way is safer, because the first one will return the oposite of wether length is 0 or not and the extra ! will transform to the oposite of the boolean.

Comment: @Modelesq make sure both of those arrays has items otherwise it will return empty

Comment: @Burimi Yep I now how `!!` works I just don't see what safety it is adding in this case, since `length` is always an unsigned integer?

Comment: @Aaron It does not work with this case, but in cases where you expect a boolean. It is very important to make it a habit IMO.

Comment: @Burimi No it *does* work without `!!` in this case. What does using `!!` add?

Comment: @Aaron this went way far that I thought. So imagine var a = true; var b = [1, 2] than a === b.length is not true :D

Comment: @Burimi it is not safer. If you are willing to cast Number to Boolean that way, using Number directly in if clause is the same thing. It adds nothing to it. I personally don't like to use implicit casting and would go with `.length === 0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const elementToRender = props.student.length && props.teacher.length ?  <p>not empty</p> : <p>empty</p>
```

And then in the jsx just do:

```html
<div>
  { elementToRender }
</div>
```