# How to iterate through Redux State object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

As soon as my app loads the 'FETCH_PRODUCTS' action payload is dispatched, resulting in items sourced from the data.json file, being added to state in my products reducer. I am able to access this state
via console.log(action.payload) in both my actions and reducers files. I need to be able to iterate through the state object so I can render products from state in my Products component. However, I am unable to iterate thru the object. Ive tried with no luck, to convert it to an iterable array with Object.keys(), .values() and .entries().

This is what I get when console.log() action.payload or products in Products.js

[image]
[image]

Products.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Fade, Zoom } from "react-reveal";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import fetchProducts from "../actions/productActions";

const Products = ({ products, add }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
  const openModal = (product) => {
    setProduct(product);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setProduct(null);
  };

const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log(products)
  const renderProducts = () => {
    return products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <a href={"#" + product._id} onClick={() => openModal(product)}>
            <img src={product.image} />
          </a>

          <p>
            <a href="#">{product.title}</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>${product.price}.00</strong>
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => add(product)}>ADD TO CART</button>
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Fade bottom cascade>
      <div>Loading...</div>
         <ul>{!products ? <div>Loading...</div> : renderProducts()}</ul> 
      </Fade>
      {product && (
        <Modal isOpen={true}>
          <Zoom clear cascade>
            <div>
              <p onClick={() => closeModal()}>X CLOSE</p>
              <img src={product.image} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{product.title}</p>
              <p>${product.price}.00</p>
              Sizes
              <p>
                Available Sizes
                {product.availableSizes.map((size) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <br />
                      <span> {size} </span>
                    </>
                  );
                })}
              </p>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  add(product);
                  closeModal();
                }}
              >
                ADD TO CART
              </button>
            </div>
          </Zoom>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect((state) => ({ products: state.products.items }), {
  fetchProducts,
})(Products);
```

productActions.js

```
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS } from "../components/types";

const fetchProducts = () => async(dispatch) => {
    const result = await fetch('data/data.json');
    const data = await result.json();
  console.log(data);
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
        payload: data   
    })
}
export default fetchProducts
```

productReducers.js

```
const { FETCH_PRODUCTS } = require("../components/types");
const data = require('../data.json')
const productsReducer = (state = {}, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {items: action.payload}
            default:
                return state;
    }
}
export default productsReducer;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import productsReducer from "./reducers/productReducers";

const initialState = {};
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({ products: productsReducer }),
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but usually I use `redux-saga` to make async request ad dispatch actions

Comment: @wyfy yes the code works. Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it would be best to figure out whats wrong with my existing logic before reaching for another technology.

Comment: it is bit difficult to know what is going wrong in your code. It would help if you can provide a running version of your code. Maybe in codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't accessing the data, because you didn't get the property from the object

Your redux store for products says this whenever you `console.log(products)`

```
{products : Array(6)}
```

So as a result you have to say `products.products` to properly map the array

---

**Addressing undefined value**

The problem is you are instantly returning the component when there is no data

```
const renderProducts = () => {
    return products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <a href={"#" + product._id} onClick={() => openModal(product)}>
            <img src={product.image} />
          </a>

          <p>
            <a href="#">{product.title}</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>${product.price}.00</strong>
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => add(product)}>ADD TO CART</button>
        </li>
      );
    });
  };
```

Keep in mind that getting data takes time so you have to check if your products state is empty. This can be solve with a ternary operator:

```
return (
    <div>
        {doSomething ? something : null}
    </div>
);
```

So in your case check if the products array is empty. If yes map through the array. If no then return "no products".

```
return (
        <div>
            {products.products.length !== 0 ? <your regular routine as above) : <p>No products</p>}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: products.products gived the following error: 'Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

Comment: It takes time to get that data . You should use a ternary operator to check if the array is empty . This post should help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327681/es6-conditional-if-statement-to-check-if-arrays-are-empty

Comment: I've already done so...It throws an error saying 'products.map is not a function'. I believe that the issue is that a conditional statement wont work in this case. I think I need to call fetchProducts() asynchronously inside of Porducts.js

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out!!! Needed to change `payload: data` to  `payload: data.products` in productActions.js